# Creating two data sets from a data set to be reused again

Tags: r, split, dataset, subset

I know there are other examples out there but to be honest none of them can answer my issue, that's why I am posting this one.
I have this dataset and I want to divide this dataset based on the variable (column).
Here is the dataset link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Mldbnr1-avMDIxYmZLSnRfUDA/view?usp=sharing

Here is what I have done so far:

```
# Reading data set
power <- read.csv("data set 6.csv", na.strings="",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# SUBSETTING
Area <- as.numeric(power$Area)
City <- as.factor(power$City)
P.Winter <- as.numeric(power$P.Winter)
P.Summer <- as.numeric(power$P.Summer)


#Part 1 - Data Cleaning and Transformation
str(power)
which(power$City == "Ackland ")
which(power$City == "Auckland ")
power$City[power$City == "Ackland "] <- "Auckland"
power$City <- trimws(power$City) # remove white spaces from all of them
power <- power[!(power$City =="Sydney"), ] # removing rows that contain "Sydney" 
power <- power[!(power$Area =="-25"), ] # clear negative area
power <- power[!(power$P.Winter =="18000"), ]

#Adding new variable and calculates average power consumption
power$P.Annual <- as.numeric(power$P.Winter + power$P.Summer)/2

#To split dataset into two parts based on "City"
library(data.table)
Auckland <- data.table(power, power$City)
Auckland[, plot(P.Winter,P.Summer, P.Annual), by = list(City)]
```

But this code results in an error, not giving what I expected:

Output:

```
Auckland <- data.table(power, power$City)
> Auckland[, plot("Auckland"), by = list(City)]
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Appreciate your help
Thanks

Comment: The code you listed in the top section looks different to the code you ran in the output section - can you double check you have included the right information?

Comment: @Marius: Yes I have. The output I posted at the bottom is only for the error I am getting which is splitting the dataset into two parts. If you can see the comment on each code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question right, you just need to use the split function, it will divide your data.frame into a list based on the City:

```
#To split dataset into two parts based on "City"
library(data.table)
splittedPower <- split(power, power$City)
str(splittedPower$Auckland)
```

The output will be:

```
'data.frame':   248 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Area    : num  144 177 269 209 124 ...
 $ City    : chr  "Auckland" "Auckland" "Auckland" "Auckland" ...
 $ P.Winter: num  1685 1927 2027 1938 1580 ...
 $ P.Summer: num  1194 1487 1737 -158 1148 ...
 $ P.Annual: num  1440 1707 1882 890 1364 ...
```

Comment: Yes you're right. But it does not create a new dataset. It only prints out the result. The new split data did not appear on the data field instead it appears on the values field. I need new data to be re-used to calculate mean and standard deviation

Comment: Now, I'm a bit confused, when you run the line:

    splittedPower <- split(power, power$City)

it will split your data.frame into a list of data.frames and assign it to a new variable, which, at least for me, appeard in the data field. See:

https://imgur.com/9DDWsle

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wXWOKrwnRxq3iEPtCdSWGewFgZgdLRYv/view?usp=sharing Yeah I am confused too. Why mine appears in the values field while yours appears in the data field.

Comment: Anyway, you can keep on calculating mean and standard deviation, even if it"s in the values field.
Maybe the "dplyr" library will come in handy for you.. there are a lot of built-in functions for data manipulation.
For example:
`library(dplyr)`
`power %>%`
`group_by(City) %>%`
 `dplyr::summarise(P.Winter.mean=mean(P.Winter),`
`P.Winter.sd=sd(P.Winter))`

   Will give you an ouput:

`# A tibble: 2 x 3`
`City P.Winter.mean P.Winter.sd`
`1   Auckland      1760.512    249.9935`
`2 Wellington      1848.791    211.5836`

Comment: I finally able to use subset function to make it work as expected. I will edit your answer for other users to see.